# Username character requirements

Tags: login, membership, username

I'm looking for the guidelines on creating a username within the members' section of a WordPress site. I'm using it with a business directory and I often get people reaching out because WP is saying that the username is invalid (usually because it's too long, short, has invalid characters etc) but it won't actually tell them why, they have to just change their username until they find one it accepts. Is there some sort of guidelines that I can publish on the "create a username" page to help people with the process? For example, "must be over x letters with one uppercase and no special characters".